# UWP : Data and models access from BackgroundTask

Tags: uwp

Today my question is about BackgroundTasks in Universal Windows Platform. I want to use push notification triggered in a BackgroundTasks and an other BackgroundTasks launched periodically. But, how to access to data and models from a BackgroundTasks? Is there any way to do this? Or maybe the only solution is to separate models and data layer in external library?

Thanks

Samuel

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is by implementing the mediator pattern. I know there used to be a great library from the PRISM enterprise libraries (Microsoft Patterns & practices) that had an EventAggregator, that you could use to transmit events from your background task to the foreground process.

Someone needs to help me in answering whether this library is still a current choice for today's UWP apps or not.

But in any event, some form of event aggregation is the way to communicate between background and foreground tasks; in practicality, you have event publishers and event subscribers.

Comment: Thank you Pedro,

But these tasks could run when application is closed. So, the EventAggregator is not a solution for me.